# JNA: The specified module could not be found in compiled jar

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I have a C++ `.dll` in my java Spring Boot project.
Everything looks good and method from `.dll` is called when:

1. I run application from IDE
2. I compile file with `mvn pack & java -jar target/Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I tried to copy project to another machine and I got this problem:

1. When I run application from IDE everything is ok
2. When I run same command on project `mvn pack & java -jar target/Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and it's called `.dll` method it crash with message error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.`

```
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412) ~[jna-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0 (b4)]`.
```

Note: I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable on both machines.

If I move .dll file in project root directory it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using JNA inside your project. JNA requires some native libraries be properly installed. E.g. it needs `jnidispatch.dll` for Windows platform.

For your case, you need to download the required native libs, e.g. https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/lib/native/win32, and put it into a directory where can be searched by your JAVA.